# News aggregator for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, web-services, web-scraping, python-newspaper

I am writing a little news sentiment analysis app - in python. I want to prepare a database of news articles to train my classifier on, so  I am wondering what is my best course of action for fetching news articles off of the web. I looked at [newspaper](http://newspaper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), which looks like a cool module and very generic, but what I am looking for is a way of fetching old news articles - i.e all news articles of 2014. newspaper only uses RSS feeds that never go too far back. Another option would be writing a scraper for google news, and filtering by date in the url, or using API's of publishers like NYT (they have an API).

What is the best way to create a news article database like this? Is there a tool/database on the web I can use to get the articles?

Comment: Don't most news websites use RSS? It's probably easier to [parse that](https://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries) than to go scrape the website directly, or to hope each site maintains and exposes some API.

Comment: @Cyber - true, and newspaper already makes it very easy to do it. But RSS feeds never let you access old articles, and I need to go back..